# ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.amazon.comhttps', port=443): Max retries exceeded

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Scrapping data from amazon got me this error:

> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.amazon.comhttps', port=443): Max retries exceeded

I don't know what the issue is. I tried using `try` and `except` block in the main, it said connection failed.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

# Function to extract Product Title
def get_title(soup):

    try:
        # Outer Tag Object
        title = soup.find("span", attrs={"id":'productTitle'})
        
        # Inner NavigatableString Object
        title_value = title.text

        # Title as a string value
        title_string = title_value.strip()

    except AttributeError:
        title_string = ""

    return title_string

# Function to extract Product Price
def get_price(soup):

    try:
        price = soup.find("span", attrs={'id':'priceblock_ourprice'}).string.strip()

    except AttributeError:

        try:
            # If there is some deal price
            price = soup.find("span", attrs={'id':'priceblock_dealprice'}).string.strip()

        except:
            price = ""

    return price

# Function to extract Product Rating
def get_rating(soup):

    try:
        rating = soup.find("i", attrs={'class':'a-icon a-icon-star a-star-4-5'}).string.strip()
    
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            rating = soup.find("span", attrs={'class':'a-icon-alt'}).string.strip()
        except:
            rating = "" 

    return rating

# Function to extract Number of User Reviews
def get_review_count(soup):
    try:
        review_count = soup.find("span", attrs={'id':'acrCustomerReviewText'}).string.strip()

    except AttributeError:
        review_count = ""   

    return review_count

# Function to extract Availability Status
def get_availability(soup):
    try:
        available = soup.find("div", attrs={'id':'availability'})
        available = available.find("span").string.strip()

    except AttributeError:
        available = "Not Available" 

    return available


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    #HEADERS for request
    HEADERS = ({'User-Agent': 'here will be my user agent', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})

    # webpage url
    URL = 'https://www.amazon.in/s?k=shades+for+women&sprefix=shades%2Caps%2C395&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_2_6'
    
    #http req
    webpage  = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")
    
    # fetch links as list of tag objects
    links = soup.find_all("a", attrs = {'class':'a-link-normal s-no-outline'})

    links_list = []
    
    for link in links:
        links_list.append(link.get('href'))
        
    d = {"title": [], "price": [], "rating": [], "reviews": [], "availability": []}
    
    for link in links_list:
        new_webpage =  requests.get("https://www.amazon.com" + link, headers = HEADERS)
            
        new_soup = BeautifulSoup(new_webpage.content, "html.parser")
        
        d['title'].append(get_title(new_soup))
        d['price'].append(get_price(new_soup))
        d['rating'].append(get_rating(new_soup))
        d['reviews'].append(get_review_count(new_soup))
        d['availability'].append(get_availability(new_soup))
        
    
    
    amazon_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
    amazon_df ['title'].replace('', np.nan, inplace = True)
    amazon_df  =  amazon_df .dropna(subset = ['title'])
    amazon_df .to_csv("amazon_data.csv", header = True, index = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you take `href` attribute from the tag, you get the full link (`https://amazon.in/foo/bar`), but not just `/foo/bar`.

That's why you should change this line of code:

`new_webpage = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com" + link, headers = HEADERS)`

I guess that's where the problem occurs.